# How to update ngModel's $modelValue based on the $viewValue update by user input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

Say I have the following directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            scope.$watch('ngModel', function() {
                ngModelCtrl.$modelValue = 'foo';
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And the following html:

```
<input ng-model="name" my-directive></input>
```

Basically, whenever the user changes the input, `my-directive` would ideally change the internal model value to "foo" while leaving the view value untouched.

But when I print out `$scope.name` in the corresponding controller, it doesn't log "foo", it logs whatever the user entered in.

It would seem that `ngModelCtrl.$modelValue` is not what the controller is accessing -- am I approaching this problem incorrectly?

(Also watching the `ngModel` in the scope feels really wrong, but I'm not sure of any other way. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!)

Comment: Instead of watching ngModel you can use `$viewChangeListeners` which is specifically designed for this purpose. But why do you want to set `$modelValue` different than the viewValue?

Comment: I'd like users to be able to enter in comma-delimited data, but have the underlying model store the information as an array.

Comment: Like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/pWpnup?p=preview

Comment: Same as Cody (above) -- I have to parse a `type="tel"` and provide a `$viewValue` mask while preserving the `$modelValue` as an integer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are looking for view change, you should never register a watch. ngModelController's [`$viewChangeListeners`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewChangeListeners) are specifically designed for this purpose and to avoid creating any additional watch on the ngModel. You can also remove 2 way binding set up on the ngModel.

I can think of this way.

```
.directive('myDirective', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          /*Register a viewchange listener*/
          ngModelCtrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function(){ 
              /*Set model value differently based on the viewvalue entered*/
              $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign(scope, ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.split(',')); 
          });
        }
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/pWpnup?p=preview)**

While thinking about it the other way around (Credits @Cody) it becomes more concise and appropriate while using a `$parser`.

```
 ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) { return val.split(',') });
```

Comment: For future reference, I checked out `$parsers`, and I think I found a bit more concise solution: `ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) { return val.split(',') })`.

Comment: No, you are right.. I don't know why i did not think about it the other way around, probably really late to sleep i guess. :) here actually everytime the value is changed we are assigning an array to the ngModel viewvalue as well but it gets stringified...